# Are CCS servers load-balancing upstreams, in case of multiple app servers?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Here's my scenario.

Client devices send upstream to CCS, which forwards them, as intended, to my app server (C libstrophe + stunnel), which acknowledges and treats them.

If i launch 2 instances of my app server (2 xmpp persistent channels), i see upstreams from the devices dispatched to server instance #1 OR server #2, never both, and apparently well balanced.

From a scalability stand point, it would be a nice feature  to use in production, but as i found no validation of this behavior in the docs, i wonder if i can rely on it?

Thanks for your help.